# google oauth with nextjs

Tags: next.js, oauth, redirect-uri

I've tried following numerous tutorials for this, and it seems like something that should be very straightforward.  However, I am consistently getting either `invalid_request` or `redirect_uri_mismatch` error responses whenever I attempt to authenticate my test user with Google.

`app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          response_type: "code",
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google",
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        }
      }
    })
  ]
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

`app/NavBar.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex bg-slate-200 p-5">
      <Link className="mr-5" href="/">
        NextJS
      </Link>
      <Link className="mr-5" href="/users">
        Users
      </Link>
      <Link href="api/auth/signin">Sign In</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

On localhost, upon clicking "Sign in with google", it always shows the following error response:

[image]

But when comparing my redirect_uri in the headers to the redirect_uri I have set up in google cloud, they appear to match.

[image]

[image]

I have tried adding other users to the test user whitelist and logging into those, logging in with other browsers, re-creating the app in Google Cloud and regenerating credentials, and clearing my  cache / attempting the request in an incognito window.

What's interesting is that the tutorial I was following did not explicitly state to include response_type, redirect_uri, and scope in the GoogleProvider setup - only clientId and clientSecret were specified. If I omit these completely and **only** pass in clientId and clientSecret, I still get the `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

Comment: did you add `http://localhost:3000` to the "Authorized JavaScript origins" in your credentials in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?

Comment: Did you double-check that you're using the correct client ID in your app?

Comment: @grekier yes, http://localhost:3000 is in Authorized JavaScript origins.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I've double- and triple-checked this, even tried generating new credentials, and it's still giving me the same error.